# Youtube api response not providing data

Tags: javascript, axios, youtube

I'm trying to make a request to google using a dynamic query.  I have more or less copied my process from another project in which the request works fine.  I have 'enabled' the api in a new project folder on the google api dashboard and used a new API key.

First of all here is the code from the working version:

```
axios
            .get(
                `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${YOUTUBE_API}&type=video&part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=${selectedTrack}`
            )
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                setVideo(response.data.items[0].id.videoId);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setLoading(true);
                console.log(err.response);
            });
```

And from the one that doesn't work :

```
const aTag = document.querySelectorAll(".movie");
    console.log(aTag);
    for (let i = 0; i < aTag.length; i++) {
        aTag[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
            const title = aTag[i].childNodes[1].alt;
            axios.get(
                `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${API_KEY}&type=video&part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=${title}`
            )
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log("res", response);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.response);
                });
        });
```

In the one that works I get a {data} object which includes the videoId of response.data.items etc, but on the one that doesn't, I get the following response:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?k…xResults=1&q=Zack%20Snyder%27s%20Justice%20League", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=............
```

I'm not super experienced so I expect that I've missed something obvious - any advice is very welcome!

Update: when I follow the url, it says API key is invalid.  As I said I've been through the process of creating new API credentials and enabling on the dashboard, maybe there is something else missed though

Comment: It seems a cors problem. Maybe when it set Youtube API was given to specific IPs or domains a authorization to use the API. Are both cases in applications with different addresses?

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this for anyone who might have the same problem, although I don't completely understand it.  In the end it looks like the problem was with axios not responding as it should.  I didn't see any errors to indicate this but to get things working I changed to an async function without axios, and fetched json data that way.

Chaining .then like that is admittedly not very elegant but here is the working code anyway:

```
async function youtube() {
    await fetch(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=AIzaSyDUppjf_r8veyOTZQ9PCFwlburDc9693-c&type=video&q=${title}` +
            `trailer`
    )
        .then((result) => {
            const newRes = result.json();
            return newRes;
        })
        .then((newRes) => {
            embedCode = newRes.items[0].id.videoId;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.response);
        });
    const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedCode}`);
}
```